# why is Vue complaining when code is actually working

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

Vue error in console

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Proxy.render (app.js:51693)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:55951)
```

I'm creating a chat app my query is returning valid json and when i run it, it works but Vue complains as above in console. I have tried all combinations to get rid of it.
Query from Laravel returns this..

```
[{
    "id": 23,
    "name": "exercitationem",
    "type": "private",
    "created_at": "2020-11-06T22:48:50.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-06T22:48:50.000000Z",
    "users": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hairy Harry",
        "email": "h@123456.com",
        "color": "#FF0000",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-07-08T17:16:03.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-07-08T17:16:03.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
            "room_id": 23,
            "user_id": 1
        }
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Skinny Seamus",
        "email": "skinny@skinny123.com",
        "color": null,
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-07-22T15:21:19.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-07-22T15:21:19.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
            "room_id": 23,
            "user_id": 4
        }
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Art Fartagas",
        "email": "art@kkkkkkkkk.com",
        "color": null,
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-08-21T15:13:24.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-21T15:13:24.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
            "room_id": 23,
            "user_id": 5
        }
    }]
}]
```

this value is passed to `selectedroom:[]`
It has the room details and users associated with it.
When i run this in Vue template like this `{{roomdetails.name}}`, it returns nothing but if I run it through a computed like this

```
    computed:{
            thisroomdetails(){
              return this.selectedroom[0];
             }
```

then run `{{thisroomdetails.name}}` it works BUT Vue in console complains like start of this post. Anybody have any clue as to what is going on here. Thanks

Ok I tried the solution v-if but still vue complaining. I had no problem with other queries like getting messages etc. This is what I got now.

```
<template>


 <div class="col">
    <div>

         <div v-if="thisroomdetails" class="roomnamediv"> {{thisroomdetails.name}}</div>
 
         <div
          v-if="thisroomdetails.users"
          v-for="youserx in thisroomdetails.users"
          :class="activeConversation === youserx.id ? 'selectedconv' : 'convusers' "
          >
         {{ youserx.name }}
        </div>

 
    </div>
 </div> 


</template>



 <script>


    

    export default {
    
      props: ['fetchMessages','roomdetails'],

      data() {
        return {
                activeConversation:null
   
                }
       },

       methods:{
         getRelativeMessages(val){
            this.activeConversation=val.id
            return this.fetchMessages(val);

         }

     },

     computed:{
               thisroomdetails(){
                      return this.roomdetails[0];
                }

     }
 }

 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That does solve the problem after all. Though, I cant figure out why when i am dealing with message results it does not happen. Maybe a more complicated query taking more time?

Answer (score 1):

This happens in the initial rendering when the data is still not available, so to avoid that warning try to add a conditional rendering in your template :

```
 {{roomdetails && roomdetails.name}}
```

or use `v-if` :

```
<div v-if="roomdetails">{{roomdetails.name}}</div>
```